# Probability integration notation: integrating with respect to X over a set involving $Y$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A$ be the set $Y^{-1}(B)$, where $Y$ and $X$ are independent random variables, defined on a common background space with probability function $P$. We wish to calculate $$\int_{A} X \ dP$$
Now the notes I am reading do something I don't quite understand: $$\int_A X \ dP = \int_{(Y \in A)} \ X \ dP = \int 1(Y \in A) \ X \ dP = \int 1_{A}(y) \cdot x \ d(X,Y)(P)(x,y)$$
Why did $A$ become $(Y \in A)$? What is $1(Y \in A)$? What happened in the final equality?

Comment: Should have been $(Y\in B)$ instead of $(Y\in A)$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$$
1(Y \in A) = \begin{cases} 1, & Y \in A \\ 0, & Y \not \in A \end{cases}
$$
and
$$
1_A(y) = \begin{cases} 1, & y \in A \\ 0, & y \not \in A \end{cases}
$$

Both are indicator functions.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, $1_{Y\in A}=1_A\circ Y$. This responses your first ask.

Then, you have

$\int_\Omega 1_{Y\in A}(\omega)X(\omega)dP(\omega)=\int_\Omega (1_A\circ Y)(\omega)X(\omega)dP(\omega)$

But the last is precisely $E[(1_A\circ Y)X]$, which can be calculated as $\int x 1_A(y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)d\lambda(x)\otimes\lambda(y)$, which is the final term of your equality.

Comment: OP didn't mention the existence of a joint density.

Comment: This does not address the typo in the text, which is probably the main cause of the OP's doubts.